# Do I need to calculate the signature every time I make a AWS request?

Tags: amazon-web-services

For some reason, I have to access AWS service via HTTP request.
In every request, a signature is needed in Authorization field in the HTTP header.

Since 'x-amz-date' field is needed in calculate the signature, does it means that I have to recalculate the signature every time I make a request to AWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must calculate signature for every request.

The motivation of signature is not only authenticating your account, but also protecting integrity of the exchanged data. So the signature must contains some info about the exchanged data of each request.

Comment: +1 with this side-note: AWS does allow a few minutes of clock skew, so if you are simply retrying a failed request for some reason, such as a transient error, re-signing should not be needed in the case when the request is re-sent almost immediately.